# Finding the size of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to adapt the size of the second node (thea circle that contains the checkmark) to the height of the rectangle (first node) automatically. I want it to have the height of the rectangle, how can I extract it? Thanks

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}


\newcommand{\teacher}[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
\draw (0,0) node[left=0.35cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt] {#1}  node[circle,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,line width=1pt,inner sep=1pt] {\Large \color{red}\faCheck}; 
 }
}


\begin{document}

\teacher{Hello\\World}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways to achieve this, but you can grab coordinates of anchors of nodes via `\pgfgetlastxy` and then use these to calculate the size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\teacher}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[
            align=center, 
            fill=violet!20, 
            draw=violet, 
            rounded corners, 
            line width=1pt, 
            inner sep=5pt
        ] (n) {#1};
        \path (n.north);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\nNorthX}{\nNorthY};
        \path (n.south);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\nSouthX}{\nSouthY};
        \node[
            circle, 
            fill=violet!20, 
            draw=violet, 
            line width=1pt, 
            inner sep=1pt,
            minimum height={\nNorthY-\nSouthY-\pgflinewidth},
            anchor=west,
            xshift={-\pgflinewidth}
        ] at (n.east) {\Large \color{red}\faCheck}; 
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\teacher{Hello\\World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Is there a way to stock the size (radius) of the circle? I want to use it to set the size of a picture in \includegraphics inside a node

Comment: @stargazer45 Well, the radius of the circle is `0.5*(\nNorthY-\nSouthY)` as long as you don't overwrite the values stored in these macros. You can always use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mymacro}{\myvalue}` to store things in macros in the context of PGF/Ti*k*Z.

Comment: thank you so much it works perfectly

Comment: @stargazer45 If you want to place a picture inside the node that is actually larger, maybe a [`path picture`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.6) could be what you are looking for.